# Constructor parameter is an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have a class with this constructor:

```
Artikel(String name, double preis){
    this.name = name;
    verkaufspreis = preis;
    Art = Warengruppe.S;
```

I have a second class with this constructor:

```
Warenkorb(String kunde, Artikel[] artikel){
    this.kunde = kunde;
    artikelliste = artikel;
    sessionid = s.nextInt();
    summe = 0;
    for(Artikel preis : artikel){
        summe += preis.verkaufspreis;
    }
}
```

How do i get an Artikel into the Warenkorb and the artikelliste array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Warenkorb("Dieter", new Artikel[] {new Artikel("Kartoffel", 0.25))};
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: mmmm... Kartoffel... food is the only way I'm going to remember any of my Deutsch.

Comment: Your spelling is great ;).

I am dying of jealousy, i also want to be a java guru...

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
Artikel[] artikels = new Artikel[2];
artikels[0] = new Artikel("John Doe", 0);
artikels[1] = new Artikel("Jane Doe", 1);
Warenkorb w = new Warenkorb("something", artikels);
```

Your question isn't really clear on what you want to do...

Comment: well we covered 2 possibilities :)

Comment: +1. Exactly, you're like Tweedle-Dee and Tweedle-Dum. (and I meant that in the best possible way :)

Comment: yeah, what are the German equivalents for Jane Doe and John Doe?

Answer (score 2):

And, looks like you're using Java 1.5+ anyway, try this alternative for Warenkorb:

```
Warenkorb(String kunde, Artikel...artikel){
        this.kunde = kunde;
        artikelliste = artikel;
        sessionid = s.nextInt();
        summe = 0;
        for(Artikel preis : artikel){
                summe += preis.verkaufspreis;
        }
}
```

Written like this, you can get rid of the ugly Array notation and construct a Warenkorb like this:

```
new Warenkorb("Dieter", new Artikel("Kartoffel", 0.25)};
new Warenkorb("Günther", new Artikel("Kartoffel", 0.25), new Artikel("Tomate", 0.25)};
```

Comment: Yep, varargs are the way to go here. +1

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using an Iterable instead of an Array:

```
Warenkorb(String kunde, Iterable<? extends Artikel> artikel){
    this.kunde = kunde;
    artikelliste = artikel;
    sessionid = s.nextInt();
    summe = 0;
    for(Artikel preis : artikel){
            summe += preis.verkaufspreis;
    }
}
```

Can still be constructed using the other array based syntax but also:

```
new Warenkorb("Buffy", Arrays.asList(new Artikel("foo",0.0), new Artikel("bar",1.0));
```

works with any implementation of `Iterable` such as `ArrayList` or `HashSet` etc